# I'm trying to swap two values , while running the code im getting this error " Incompatible types. Found: 'int', required: 'int[]' "

Tags: java

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SwapingValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int[] arr = input.nextInt();
     swap(arr,1,5);
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
    static void swap(int[] arr, int index1, int index2) {
        int temp = arr[index1];
        arr[index1] = arr[index2];
        arr[index2] = temp;
    }
}
```

Error: Incompatible types. Found: 'int', required: 'int[]'

Comment: `next()` doesn't return a `int[]`  .

Answer (score -1):

I should think you will want to fill the arr[] array with multiple integer values but the way you are doing it obviously wont do the job. You will need to get the User to enter several integer values and this can indeed be done in a single User entry into the Console Window.

There are a number of ways to do this but the most common would be do utilize a looping mechanism of some kind, for example:

**Ask the User to enter Ten integer values:**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a sequence of ten integer numbers");
int[] arr = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a value for index " + i + ": --> ");
    try {
        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input! Try again...\n");
        input.nextLine();  // Consume the newline from the ENTER Key hit.
        i--;
    }
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The arr[] Array is full!");
```

The above code also validates the input given by the User.

Comment: Yeah... this solved my query.... thank you